# issue with jsTree and child elements

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I'm using jsTree to create a file structure visualizer in ASP.NET.  I've found that I can render tree structures just fine, as long as all the nodes are at the root level.  When I incorporate child nodes, they're not rendered.  I've tried using (supposedly) known-good JSON from stackoverflow and other help sites, and none of it works, even when I just copy-and-paste the provided code with no modifications.

I'm using jQuery 1.8.0 and jsTree 1.0-rc3 in Visual Studio 2012 on a pre-existing .NET 4.5 Web project.  The scripts and uls are in a Web User Control.  I've tested this in IE 8, Firefox 21.0 and Chrome 28.0, all with the same result.

The first tree is a test, based on an existing menu in the PHP application I'm porting to .NET.

The HTML for that is straightforward:

```
<div class="span-24" id="treeheader">    
<ul> 
    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="header-tab">Header/Trailer</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" id="employee-tab">Employee</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" id="dependent-tab">Dependent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Toggle Advanced</a></li> 
</ul>
```

The script that treeifies that ul:

```
        jQuery("#treeheader").jstree({
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm"], // "hotkeys"],
        "core": { "initially_open": ["hhtml_1"] }
    });
```

So far, so good.  For the actual file structure, however, I can't hardcode the ul; I'm instead receiving json from a service and using it to construct the ul for me:

```
        $('#treeviewer').jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "data": "834 - v5010 File",
            "attr": "phtml_1",
            "state": "open",
            "children":
                [
                    {
                        "data": "BGN - Beginning Segment",
                        "attr": "phtml_2"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "REF - Transaction Set Policy Number",
                        "attr": "phtml_3"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "DTP LOOP - File Effective Date",
                        "attr": "phtml_4"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "N1 - Sponsor Name",
                        "attr": "phtml_5"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "N1 - Payer",
                        "attr": "phtml_6"
                    }
                ]
        },
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "url": "../../scripts/Default/style.css",
            "dots": false
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm"]
    });
});
```

...in an empty div:

```
<div class="span-24" id="treeviewer">
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points to upload the image that shows the results, but the top menu clearly shows four distinct elements, all aligned with each other, whereas the second tree shows only the root element.  I've tried a variety of variations on the json; this is the simplest of the bunch (in that all the children are children of one root node, as opposed to having the branching structure of the test data).

I don't see anything wrong with the json, and no errors are being reported.  Is there any kind of processing or formatting that I might have to do to make this work?  Or is this potentially an issue with this version of jsTree?  Thanks in advance.